# Is the HTML content published using Google Drive Site Publishing indexed by Search Engines?

Tags: search-engine, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-search

Ref: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html

Is the HTML content published using Google Drive Site Publishing indexed by Search Engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is, as long as the files are publicly shared.

Comment: +1 because @AliAfshar is a better source than previous answerer

Comment: Have a look at https://www.google.com/search?q=site:googledrive.com&filter=0 - all results are blocked due to a robots.txt file.
 According to https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449: "While Google won't crawl or index the content of pages blocked by robots.txt, we may still index the URLs if we find them on other pages on the web"

Answer (score 2):

No, Please see the Robots.txt file.

https://googledrive.com/robots.txt

User-agent: *
Disallow: /

Comment: They are indexed, but their content isn't indexed, according to: https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449